Dimension spar webs and spar caps
Hello aviation community!
I would like to ask how one proceeds with dimensioning the spar caps and spar webs of a wing? As in the process of doing so.
This is just based on some experimental calculation for a small UAV aircraft I am doing as a project. All we know is that we are using a an airfoil of NACA 4412 type. And it would be made of a CFRP material. And also that we would only have one spar, most likely in I-beam form going throught the wing.
So what would your process be or what would you recommend me to do?

Small UAV sized aircraft benefit from squared-cubed scaling laws in a way that the size of the structure is seldom determined by traditional calculations based on flight loads.  Instead, they are typically sized by minimum gague (the smallest amount of material you are willing to use given your processes) and/or handling loads -- the loads exerted on the aircraft by handling -- picked up, put down, thrown in the back of a car, assembled, disassembled, dropped, etc.
